# How to stop logged in users from accessing login/register pages with Flask-Stormpath?

Tags: python, flask, authorization, flask-login, stormpath

I'm building a Flask app which uses Stormpath and Flask-Stormpath for auth. I wish to prevent a logged in user from accessing the /login or /register pages (since this doesn't make much sense - a logged in user has no need to log in, and you are registered by definition if you are already logged in). I have attempted a solution in my custom login page template, doing something along the lines of:

```
{% block page_heading %}

    {% if user.given_name %}
        Already Logged in as {{ user.given_name }}
    {% else %}
        Enter your credentials
    {% endif %}

{% endblock page_subheading %}
```

If a user is currently signed in, user.given_name will be defined and the page_heading block will take the 'already logged in' message, and otherwise the 'enter your credentials' message (in the normal case of an unauthenticated user going attempting to log in). I use the same construct to show the login form or more error text. However, this attempt does not work: it is as though user.given_name always reverts to undefined when a logged in user visits /login. This implies that if someone is logged in, and visits /login they are then logged out - this would explain the failure of my attempt at a solution.

Given the above and after consulting the docs, I might be able to use is_authenticated(); not through Flask-Stormpath, however, but through the underlying Flask-Login module, since Flask-Stormpath always sets this to return True, per the docs, but I have no idea how to go about this.

Additionally, my approach is hacky - I feel a better solution would reside in the Python side of the app.

So my question is this: What is the most sensible way to detect a user is logged in and given this, prevent them from accessing, or redirect them from, the /login and /register pages? Perhaps there is a magical decorator somewhere that is the opposite to

```
@login_required
```

or a stormpath built-in 'unauthorised' group that I could use as in

```
@groups_required(['unauthorised'])
```

Or, maybe I was on the right lines with my original attempt.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Update: I have just tried my original approach (the template based solution) with the /register page and got the desired behaviour. Things still don't work for /login. Looking more and more likely that if a logged in user visits /login, they are logged out, and then the login page is shown. Not sure how to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/viewdecorators/#view-decorators) containing the code below. It will redirect logged in users to another page if they try to access the login page.

```
if current_user.is_authencticated():
    return redirect (url_for('home'))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Where would this code go exactly? With flask-stormpath, the view functions for /login and /register are internal to the library.

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate the  help

Comment: current_user.is_authenticated is what now works since that is a boolean, cannot be invoked like a function anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo!

So, I'm the author of Flask-Stormpath, I thought I'd jump in here. Instead of trying to modify the behavior of login / register (which I wouldn't recommend, as we change that stuff periodically with library releases), a better solution is to simply hide those URLs from the user once they've logged in.

Many websites have a top navbar, for instance, which initially says "Login" and "Register" somewhere. But, once you've logged in, those buttons change to something else, usually "Dashboard" or similar.

This way, a user isn't able to go to /login or /register unless they specifically type into the browser and attempt to go there manually.

I think this is the ideal scenario, which you can accomplish using template conditional logic:

```
{% if user %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hey! I have been doing this - there is no way for a logged in user to access /login or /register from within my app. It was the case of them entering /login in the address bar manually I was referring to in my question. Sorry, I should've mentioned that in my question!

Comment: @rdegges I'm actually shocked to hear this kind of answer from a flask-extension developer. This undefined behavior could lead to vulnerabilities in your website. It's the login functionality, the core of the website, the most valuable and sensitive information, and you propose just to **hide** the link? LOL